# AngularJS: Dropdown directive with custom ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a dropdown directive where i want to specify the selects ng-options  "option value" and "option description" attributes by specifying them with the directives attributes. See code for a better understanding...

Here is my directive. This will obviously not work, but i think it will describe what i'm trying to do...

```
app.directive('dropdown', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        array: '='
    },
    template:   '<label>{{label}}</label>' +
                '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="a[{{optValue}}] as a[{{optDescription}}] for a in array">' +
                    '<option style="display: none" value="">-- {{title}} --</option>' +
                '</select>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.label = attrs.label;  
        scope.title = attrs.title;
        scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
        scope.optDescription = attrs.Description;
    }
};
```

});

...and here is how i want to use it

```
<dropdown title="Choose ferry" label="Ferries" array="ferries" opt-value="Id" opt-description="Description"></dropdown>
<dropdown title="Choose route" label="Routes" array="routes"  opt-value="Code" opt-description="Name"></dropdown>
```

**And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wXV6Z/1/**

If you have a solution to this problem, or perhaps more likely, have a different opinion on how to tackle it, please let me know!

Thanks
/Andreas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this can work. The only change you need to make is to remove the curly braces around `a[{{optValue}}]` and `a[{{optDescription}}]`, as you don't need to interpolate there.

`optValue` and `optDescription` are already strings in scope, so `a[optValue]` and `a[optDescription]` will make your code work just fine, as they are expressions evaluated in your directive's scope.

[Here's an updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXV6Z/4/).

Comment: Good call. Since each part is being evaluated by Angular, it will be able to pull those values out of the $scope.

Comment: This helped me resolve an issue I was having in my own custom directive doing something very similar to this.  Thanks!